# How to assign a value to character pointer in a structure and store it in the form of queue

Tags: c

This is my code
After inserting characters in the queue, If I pop the elements, the characters(name and priority) will display the latest data which I have entered, the previous data will be deleted.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

int NAME = 20;
int num = 1001;

typedef struct patient { 
    int age; 

    char *name;
    char *priority; 

    struct patient* next; 

} Patient; 

Patient* newPatient(int age, char *p, char *name) 
{ 
    Patient* temp = (Patient*)malloc(sizeof(Patient)); 
    temp->age = age; 
    temp->priority = p; 
    temp->next = NULL; 
    temp->name = name;
    //strcpy(temp->name,name);
    printf("name is%s",temp->name);
    printf("priority is%s",temp->priority);

    return temp; 
} 

void addPatient(Patient** head, int age, char *p, char *name) 
{ 
    Patient* start = (*head); 
    Patient* temp = newPatient(age, p, name);

    if (atol((*head)->priority) < age) { 

        temp->next = *head; 
        (*head) = temp; 
    } 
    else { 

        while (start->next != NULL && 
            atol(start->next->priority) < age) { 
            start = start->next; 
        } 

        temp->next = start->next; 
        start->next = temp; 
    } 
}
```

I'm new to coding please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `Patient* newPatient(int age, char *p, char *name)`:
You are not allocating new memory for `priority` and `name`.
Either you always pass a newly allocated memory for `p` and `name` which is being pointed to by `priority` and `name` OR allocate new memory for `priority` and `name` in `newPatient()` and then do `strcpy()`